# How to appropriately test Ethernet hardware?

Tags: signal, ethernet, hardware

How should I appropriately test the Ethernet of my device? I have some ideas:

1. Measure signal integrity between the MCU and the PHY or Switch devices (like RMII)
2. Measure the signal integrity of the proper Ethernet signals like TX+/ TX- and RX+/ RX- (measure, voltage levels and rising/fall times)

Should any of the above be sufficient to say the Ethernet, in electrical terms, is good in my device? What should be the criteria?

Comment: The Ethernet standard (IEEE 802.3-2018) is freely available from ieee.org. The only way to say for sure if your Ethernet device is "good" is to check that it meets all the specifications in the standard that apply to it. Caution: the standard is 5600 pages long.

Answer (score 2):

1. I would check the rise times of the 25 or 50MHz signals and make sure they conform with the rise times required in the datasheet of the phy. An RMII shouldn't be that difficult to use since there are no tranmission lines involved. Make sue the PCB has a ground plane and the 50MHz signals are on the top layer (with the ground layer below) for best results. If you really wanted to go crazy with testing you could check all the RMII signals with a logic analyzer and make sure there is no errors, but this would come with a great cost in time.
2. Checking the TX/RX lines is more difficult. To measure the lines you'd need a differential probe (200MHz but ideally 500Mhz or more, diff probes are not cheap) to measure the differential signals of each pair. Some scopes provide test patterns (with additional cost) to help make sure the eye diagram [conforms to the timing standards](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/AN2686-Ethernet-Compliance-Test-10BASET-100BASETX-1000BASET.pdf).

[image]
Source: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/AN2686-Ethernet-Compliance-Test-10BASET-100BASETX-1000BASET.pdf

> Should any of the above be sufficient to say the Ethernet, in
> electrical terms, is good in my device? What should be the criteria?

Noise can cause timing to be off. Too much EMI caused by other sources on your PCB can cause a signal to change from a high voltage state to a low voltage state, this would show up as bit errors in ethernet packets (or worst case a register on the phy to be improperly set if the error is in RMII). I think the criteria should be make sure the phy is properly configured, and packets can be sent from your device to another device with very little error (like losing less then one in a million or billion packets)

Comment: Many recent (and some that aren't so recent) scopes can display the difference between (for example) channel 1 and 2, so you can use a 4-channel scope to measure 2 differential pairs without having to use differential probes (but you do use up two input channels for each differential pair). Fortunately, Ethernet doesn't use a lot of pairs...

Comment: I would suggest this, but it can be more noisy than a differential probe, and much harder to get the same speeds as most scopes come with passive probes.

Comment: Not to be argumentative, but I'd guess more people have normal active probes than differential probes. Not to mention they cost less--even a 400 MHz diff probe is around $5-6K, whereas the last time I considered selling my (700MHz) active probes, it seems like they were selling for around $1200/apiece.

Comment: I thought the same thing until I got a diff probe, they are worth it

Comment: I'm not saying they aren't worth it. Only that there are other options that may suffice for his needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this but I have performed basic Ethernet testing in the past,

Assuming that you can verify that the Ethernet connection works in the first place the following might be the right approach for you.

We were concerned with reliability over long periods of time, we connected our DUT (Device Under Test) to a PC, the PC ran software called Iperf to send data to the DUT with a defined packet size at a defined data rate. We would run this test for 24+ hours to assess the performance of the transfer, the DUT would log the events in a csv file that we would verify in post.

We defined multiple test scenarios to put the DUT into before running the test to ensure we verified the performance under all possible use cases.

Key measurements from this test method are a drop in Transfer rate (DUT unable to receive data at higher rates) & packet loss (Is it consistent, do you get large spikes of packet loss when the devices starts doing something else in the background etc).

This method is not really good for pinpointing a issue, but is good to verify the long term integrity of the connection.

Comment: It's a decent method of testing, but the OP asked how to verify **electrically** that the Ethernet is good.